# How to use the pnorm() function in R to verify the empirical rule?

Tags: r, math, statistics

I have no clue how to use pnorm() to do this. Empiral rule: 68% of observations are within 1 standard deviation of the mean. 95% of observations are within 2 standard deviations of the mean. 99.7% of observations are within 3 standard deviations of the mean.

Comment: This sounds like homework. There's nothing wrong with [asking HW related questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) but you should show your own code attempt.

Comment: So the problem is that this is not really a yet coding question.  Did someone tell you that you needed to use pnorm() to do this? What would you need the code to do in order to see if the empirical rule actually works? What would the data need to look like?

Answer (score 0):

`pnorm` is a function which essentially gives you the value of the CDF of the normal distribution at a given point. The default is for a standard normal distribution. Thus,

```r
pnorm(0)
#> [1] 0.5
```

is essentially telling you that 50% of the mass of the standard normal distribution lies below 0. To get the mass between two numbers, say the mass between -1.5 and 2 one would do

```r
pnorm(2) - pnorm(-1.5)
#> [1] 0.9104427
```

As I'm guessing this is a homework question, that should be enough to get you on your way to verifying the empirical rule.

Comment: Similar to the comment I left OP, please review [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-**and-answer**-homework-questions) I think it's generally best to wait for OP to provide an attempt prior to giving answers (even if they are not full answers and only meant to lead OP in the right direction).

Comment: I have and I thought I was following the first two bullets of how to answer these questions. I do in person tutoring and this is a similar (but briefer/less interactive) approach to how I would handle it in that case. If this is not an appropriate answer, please let me know what I should do differently.

Comment: I do see your point and I agree with your answer being consistent with what SO recommends. Personally (and as a former lecturer/teacher myself) I prefer waiting for an initial attempt prior to giving hints. I often found this to stimulate the question asker (student) to do more research, leading to a greater learning outcome. But I don't have an issue with your answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I definitely see both sides of it as well. In this case I debated just posting a comment telling them to do ?pnorm and read the help pages but in case they were new to programming all together, I figured I'd show how the function worked.